# geometry problem dealing with quadrilateral and proving two lines perpendicular to each other and equal in magnitude

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, vector-analysis, rotations, quadrilateral

On each side of a quadrilateral ABCD,squares are drawn.The centers of the opposite squares are joined.Show that PR and QS are perpendicular to each other and equal in magnitude.[image]

> pure geometry is becoming very lengthy,perhaps difficult.Also since ,quadrilateral is arbitrary use of coordinate geometry is not proving much helpful.

Comment: is this van aubel's theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the lower case letter represent the point in the complex plane. (e.g $a$ represents $A$).

Then $p=a+z(b-a),q=b+z(c-b),r=c+z(d-c),s=d+z(a-d)$ for $z=\frac{i+1}{2}$

Thus $$p-r=a-c+z(b-d-a+c)=\bar{z}(a-c)+z(b-d)$$ and $$q-s=b-d+z(c-a-b+d)=\bar{z}(b-d)+(a-c)$$.

But since $z=i\bar z$ they are equal and perpendicular.

Answer (score 1):

To rotate vector around any point by some angle it says to rotate this vector by this angle around a tail of the vector.

Let $R^{\alpha}(\vec{a})$ be a rotation of $\vec{a}$ by $\alpha$ and $AA_1B_2B$, $BB_1C_2C$, $CC_1D_2D$ and $DD_1A_2A$ be our squares.

Thus, we need to prove that $$R^{90^{\circ}}(\vec{SQ})=\vec{RP}.$$ 
Indeed, $$R^{90^{\circ}}(\vec{SQ})=R^{90^{\circ}}\left(\vec{SD}+\vec{DR}+\vec{RC}+\vec{CQ}\right)=\vec{SA}+\vec{RC}+\vec{RD}+\vec{QB}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\vec{RC}+\vec{CQ}+\vec{QB}+\vec{BP}=\vec{SA}+\vec{RC}+\vec{RD}+\vec{QB}$$ or
$$\vec{CQ}+\vec{BP}=\vec{SA}+\vec{RD}$$ or
$$\vec{DR}+\vec{CQ}+\vec{BP}+\vec{AS}=\vec{0},$$ which is true because
$$\sqrt2R^{45^{\circ}}\left(\vec{DR}+\vec{CQ}+\vec{BP}+\vec{AS}\right)=\vec{DC}+\vec{CB}+\vec{BA}+\vec{AD}=\vec{0}.$$